# Trying to change the name when uploading an image file using php

Tags: php, image, rename

I am trying to change the name of a file I am uploading using PHP, I know this question has already been answered but I can't find the solution using someone else's example so bear with me please.

In the code below I have set var userid to the user which is logged in. I would like that the image that get's uploaded receives the name of the user.

```
<?php

session_start();

//database connectie
include_once('db/conn.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ 

    $userid = $_SESSION['user'];
    $ran = $userid;
    $target = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

}else{
    echo "plz login before uploading an image";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `move_uploaded_file` you can declare where the image goes AND change the name of the image.

```
//Moves image to 'uploads' and saves image as '$userid.$imageFileType (e.g '31029.png')
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target . $userid . $imageFileType);
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job =)